# Размножить рабочий пример для одного элемента на множество элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу рабочий пример для одной единицы распространить на множество независимых элементов с помощью `.each()` и `$(this)`, но где-то ошибся. Массив `quantity` определяет у меня правильно, а вот `max` и `min` - как `undefined`.

В строке `$(this).find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = quantity[0] + " × ";` возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined"

Как исправить проблемы?

Исходный вариант кода:

```
var quantity = $(".li .quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g),
max = +$(".li .input-text.qty.text").attr("max"),
min = +$(".li .input-text.qty.text").attr("min");
quantity[1] = parseNumber(quantity[1]);

function fn() {
    quantity[0] > max && (quantity[0] = max);
    quantity[0] < min && (quantity[0] = min);
    $(".li .amount").text(numberWithCommas((quantity[0] * quantity[1])) + " руб");
    $(".li .quantity")[0].firstChild.data = quantity[0] + " × ";
}
$(".li #button_plus, .li #button_minus").click(function() {
    $(this).is(".li #button_plus") ? quantity[0] ++ : quantity[0] --;
    fn()
})
$(".li .input-text.qty.text").click(function() {
    quantity[0] = this.value;
    fn()
})
fn()
```

То, что хочу получить:

```
$('.cart_list .li').each(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).find(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g),
            max = +$(this).find(".input-text.qty.text").attr("max"),
            min = +$(this).find(".input-text.qty.text").attr("min");
    function fn() {
        quantity[0] > max && (quantity[0] = max);
        quantity[0] < min && (quantity[0] = min);
        $(this).find(".amount").text(numberWithCommas((quantity[0] * quantity[1])) + " руб");
        $(this).find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = quantity[0] + " × ";
    }
    $(this).find("#button_plus").click(function() {
        quantity[0]++;
        fn()
    })
    $(this).find("#button_minus").click(function() {
        quantity[0]--;
        fn()
    })
    $(this).find(".input-text.qty.text").click(function() {
        quantity[0] = this.value;
        fn()
    })
    fn()
});
```

Отдельный элемент:

```
<div class="li">
    <span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
    <div class="quantity buttons_added">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
        <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
        <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
    </div>
</div>
```

Таких блоков много, и во всех условия должны выполняться:

```
<div class="cart_list">
    <div class="li">Первый элемент</div>
    <div class="li">Второй элемент</div>
    <div class="li">Третий элемент</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: @Regent ну вроде бы шкаф собрал

Comment: @Regent 1 - ок, исправил li - когда упрощал код сходу не увидел. 2. ну, как получилось, так получилось.. вопрос к теме wordpress, история об этом умалчивает

Comment: Только не забывайте тогда, что `.text()` возвращает склеенную строку из текста всех элементов. В будущем это может навредить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Основная ошибка в том, что `this` внутри функции `fn` указывает на `window`, а не на выбранный `.cart_list .li`. Как результат - в `$this.find(".quantity")` было 0 элементов.
- C `min` и `max` никаких проблем замечено не было (в примере они вычисляются правильно).
- У кнопок `#button_plus` и `#button_minus` заменил ID на класс, потому что по правилам хорошего тона ID должен быть уникальным в рамках документах. Однако если в JS и HTML поменять обратно с класса на ID, то ничего не сломается.
- У `.input-text.qty.text` заменил обработку события `click` на обработку события `change` - в общем случае, это более правильный подход.
- Остальные изменения в коде - косметические.

```js
function parseNumber(str) {
    var regExp = /\d+/g;
    var part;
    var result = 0;
    while (part = regExp.exec(str)) {
        result = result * Math.pow(10, part[0].length) + parseInt(part[0]);
    }
    return result;
}

function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts = n.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}

$('.cart_list .li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var quantity = $this.find(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
    var basePrice = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < quantity.length; i++) {
        basePrice += quantity[i];
    }
    basePrice = parseNumber(basePrice);
    console.log(quantity);
    var $input = $this.find(".input-text.qty.text");
    var max = +$input.attr("max");
    var min = +$input.attr("min");

    function updateValue(newValue) {
        var value = +newValue;
        newValue > max && (value = max);
        newValue < min && (value = min);
        $this.find(".amount").text(numberWithCommas(value * basePrice) + " руб");
        $this.find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
        $input.val(value);
    }

    $this.find(".button_plus").click(function () {
        updateValue(+$input.val() + 1)
    });

    $this.find(".button_minus").click(function () {
        updateValue(+$input.val() - 1);
    });

    $input.change(function () {
        updateValue(this.value);
    });

    updateValue(quantity[0]);
});
```

```html
<div class="cart_list">
    <div class="li">
        <span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
        <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
            <input type="button" value="+1" class="button_plus" class="plus" />
            <input type="button" value="-1" class="button_minus" class="minus" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="li">
        <span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
        <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
            <input type="button" value="+1" class="button_plus" class="plus" />
            <input type="button" value="-1" class="button_minus" class="minus" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: все бы хорошо,но основное для чего нужен весь этот скрипт - это чтобы при клике на +/- пересчитывало сумму. в моем примере эта строчка `$(this).find(".amount").text(numberWithCommas((quantity[0] * quantity[1])) + " руб");` именно этим и занималась, а теперь это на товарах не работает..

Comment: не, все логично, если допустить, что в блоке `4 × 1.440.000 руб` 4 × скрывается (4 остается только в блоке с +/-), а напротив строчки итоговая сумма выводится значение: 5.840.000 руб

Comment: @Вася так вы же сразу об этом не сказали... Ответ исправил, теперь в `.amount` отображается общая сумма.

Comment: да, не упомянул, т.к. не подумал, что это будет существенно Итак, что имеем у меня по итогу: basePrice и quantity получаем без проблем, min и max получаем Nan ( `input type="number` с хвостом 1 в  1 как у вас) - конечно можно указать принудительно 1, 100 - тогда работает, но..события на кнопках "+" и "-" не сраабтывают (пробовал задавать и в див и в классах) По функции updateValue проходит, но работу не можем просмотреть по причинам выше

Comment: @Вася 1. Согласитесь: в моём примере всё работает, поэтому нужно искать различия между вашим кодом и моим. 2. Все эти проблемы могут возникать, есть `<input type="number>` и кнопки "+" и "-" добавляются в HTML **после** выполнения этого кода. Это важно проверить.

Comment: 1. я полностью согласен - вы большой молодец! но, мне важно, чтобы этот функционал заработал и у меня (иначе зачем столько усилий), поэтому и выношу вопросы на повестку дня - я ж без претензий..2. <input type="number> и кнопки "+" и "-"  добавляются перед var $this = $(this); (иначе не работали бы quantity и basePrice, но они ведь работаю, вот в чем прикол!) в том же цикле через `$('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div class="li">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');`

Comment: @Вася так, подождите, ещё раз: где происходит `.addItem('<div class="li">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');`? До или после кода из примера? И зачем вообще это происходит?

Comment: `.addItem('<div class="li">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');` происходит внутри блока `$('.cart_list .li').each(function() {..}` который я указывал в примере, но **ДО** кода, который написали вы. в `.addItem` как раз и формируется структура с блоками `quantity`, кнопками +/- и др..

Comment: @Вася `$(this)` внутри `.each()`, напоминаю, - это `<div class="li">`. Вы обворачиваете `<div class="li">` с помощью ещё одного `<div class="li">`?

Comment: я кажется стал догонять.. @Regent нет, не оборачиваю - структура несколько запутаннее, чем я упрощал, но тем самым скрыл важные сведения - попытаюсь объяснить: содержимое каждого элемента `$('.cart_list .li').each(function () {}` (li это на самом деле селектор, а не класс - помните, я писал что забыл поставить точку, когда упрощал) я перезаписываю в `div с классом li`, который формирую здесь `.addItem('<div class="li">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');`, а список с li соответственно скрываю. вот и получается, что `var $this = $(this);` берется с ul `.cart_list li`, а мне нужно с `<div class="li">`

Comment: @Вася можно сделать так: отдельно сделайте цикл по копированию в `'<div class="li">`, после чего запустите указанный в ответе `.each()` по новым элементам. Тогда всё должно быть нормально.

Comment: ок. @Regent а вот это `var $this = $(".li");` как я понял - не прокатит, да?

Comment: @Вася не прокатит. Но можно `$('.li').each(function() { $this = $(this); ` и так далее. Но только когда элементы уже есть.

Comment: так, заработало, только почему-то кнопки +/- прибавляют/отнимают не по 1, а сразу по 2 элемента.. хм, странно

Comment: @Вася возможно, код, навешивающий обработчик `click`, выполняется  дважды. Либо один и тот же элемент в `.each()` попадает дважды.

Comment: походу нет. после кнопки +/- срабатывает точно этот блок    `$input.change(function () {
        updateValue(this.value);
    });`
и/или этот
    `updateValue(quantity[0]);` , внутри которого и происходит увеличение...с 2 до 3 к примеру

Comment: @Вася `updateValue(quantity[0]);` выполняется всего один раз при инициализации. По поводу `.change()` - даже если бы он срабатывал, значение бы при этом не менялось. Пробовали добавить `console.log()` в `change(function() { ... }` и в саму функцию `updateValue`?

Comment: вот в этом `$input.change(function () {
        updateValue(this.value);
    });` фрагменте ошибка `this.value=3`, когда кнопка + показывает увеличение с 1 до 2

Comment: @Вася интересное дело. А можете в fiddle воспроизвести проблему? И в каком браузере такая проблема? Можно, конечно, с `change` на `click` обратно вернуть - это неудобно для пользователя, но, возможно, будет всегда правильно работать.

Comment: чейндж `change` на `click` не срабатывает. ну, вот как-то так [http://jsfiddle.net/ligisayan/Ls0wq6v1/]

Comment: @Вася _как-то так_ - этот скрипт в fiddle вообще не работает, не говоря уж про воспроизведение ошибки. Очень плохо, что я трачу по 20 минут, чтобы просто заставить fiddle работать. Например, очень долго пытался понять почему `.li` не добавляются - оказывается, в HTML было `<div id="#foot-carousel">`, а не `<div id="foot-carousel">`.  В общем, я всё-таки заставил [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0wq6v1/1/) работать, и работают поля в нём правильно. Без **воспроизводимого** примера я ничего не сделаю. Огромная куча комментариев - и всё по поводу того, что _где-то там_ не работает.

Comment: @Вася я верю, что у вас где-то проблема, но я не там, а тут, и меня тут всё работает. Поэтому только с примером. И, справедливости ради, на заданный вопрос ответ дан прямо в ответе.

Comment: спасибо за ваши все старания, но если бы я мог воспроизвести проблему в fiddle, чтобы она могла там отразиться - сомневаюсь, что она уже была бы проблемой) тогда к вам чуть измененный вопрос: почему в вашем коде, когда смотришь в консоли через `$input.change` операция сложения/вычитания не проходит, хотя там внутри содержатся `console.log("change");
        console.log(this.value);`, а у меня проходит и именно в этом кроется ключевая соль ошибки, т.к. именно через нее увеличивается/уменьшается еще на "1"

Comment: @Вася звучит как неплохой способ решения проблемы - её воспроизведение в fiddle. По поводу `$input.change` - не знаю, звучит совершенно странно. Проверяйте внимательно в какой последовательности что и сколько раз вызывается. Если идей так и не будет, то используйте костыли для решения проблемы: например, использование флага, который будет запрещать повторное изменение значения в течение, например, 200 миллисекунд.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю, что fiddle решает, но я не могу воспроизвести в нем свою проблему так, чтобы на выходе было тоже, что и меня, тем более, если код по сути тот же самый, что и вас.. а на каком этапе должно срабатывать `$input.change` - само по себе или при событиях на кнопках +/- ? судя по логам у меня - оно отрабатывает после кнопок +/-, а в вашем коде по логам это не прослеживается

Comment: @Вася по идее, `change` должно срабатывать только когда вы вписали новое значение в `input` и убрали фокус с него. При вызове `$input.val(newValue)`, например, событие `change` не должно возникать. Возможно, `change` генерирует какая-нибудь библиотека из тех, что вы используете.

Comment: у меня есть большое подозрение, что здесь `$this.find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";` (что первым отрабатывает - `(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data` или `$this.find` ?) собака зарыта. в селекторе li тоже хранится span.quantity, который скорее всего накладывается на тот, что в классе "li" отобразил это в fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0wq6v1/5/]

Comment: ибо сама сумма считается правильно, в quantity все показывает верно `<span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">720.000 руб</span>`, а вот `<input type="number">` выводит на +1 больше...

Comment: @Вася как вам уже ответили в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431891/), порядок строго слева направо. Поэтому `.quantity` ищется только внутри `$this`. Кстати, вы не пробовали в конце обработчиков `click` добавить `return false;`? Если что-то в HTML не так, и на кнопки обработчики навешиваются дважды, то это должно исправить ситуацию.

Comment: оп-па @Regent вы гений! видимо кнопки действительно отрабатывали дважды! от странно-то спасибо большое!

Comment: @Вася на здоровье. Видимо, вчера из-за жары я об этом не подумал. Но несмотря на то, что `return false;` помог, всё же поищите на досуге почему так получается, что обработчик добавляется дважды. Возможно, это весьма поможет в будущем. И отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как правильный.