# Условие поиска отрабатывает позже получения данных?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Приветствую. Есть строка на jquery. Большая вероятность, что `(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data` отрабатывает раньше, чем `$(this).find(".quantity")`

```
$(this).find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
```

мне нужно наоборот, чтобы гарантированно `$(this).find` отработало раньше `(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data`Как это сделать?

Comment: Не знаю, откуда вы взяли такое предположение, но оно в корне неверно.

Comment: @Etki это догадка, возможно не верная, но я хочу в этом убедится

Comment: Если правая часть выполняется раньше, то от чего, по-вашему, берется нулевой элемент?

Comment: @Etki от .`.quantity` - `(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data` У меня несколько классов `.quantity` на странице, мне нужно гарантированно знать, что данные берутся из $(this)

Comment: @Вася `(".quantity")` - это только строка. Значит, `(".quantity")[0]` само по себе выводит первый символ: `"."`.

Comment: @PeterOlson когда [что-то](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431677/) долго не работает, в голову приходят страшные мысли :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не надо сделать. Это выражение

```
$(this).find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
```

уже отрабатывает в таком порядке:

1. `$(this)`
2. `.find(".quantity")`
3. `[0]`
4. `.firstChild`
5. `.data = value + " x "`